# Embedding a file in Word WITHOUT an icon

Tags: microsoft-word, icons, embedding

I'm trying to embed a Word document (meeting handout) into another Word document (meeting minutes). I would like to make it more like an inline hyperlink than a document icon. Is this possible? I've tried creating a hyperlink to the document (handout), but that won't work for anyone but me, as the link is to a file on MY computer.  So, embedding is the answer, but who wants an ugly giant icon in the middle of a paragraph.  I just can't believe that Microsoft hasn't anticipated this before.  I want to be able to highlight the text in my paragraph as the "icon" to open the file.  It should look like a hyperlink does in blue text and underlined.  I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Ideas?

Comment: The reason that Word doesn't do this well is because it is primarily a word processor; not an HTML editor. The fact that it can do anything with a link is just a bonus. You should consider copying the relevant information to Word; you can copy text or make images.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed a file, your two choices for its visual representation in the document are an icon (which you can crop and resize, by the way, if the size bothers you) and the first page of the embedded file.

If you want something that looks like a hyperlink, store the meeting handout, or a copy of it, in a shared location that everyone who needs the document has access to; you can then insert a real hyperlink as you did before.